# How to migrate from Basic authentication to modern authentication in SQL server database email configuration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We are using basic authentication (smtp.office365.com) for SQL server database email SMTP.

My manager has advised me to use modern authentication instead of basic authentication for database email because they are going to disable SMTP authentication on all user accounts on the tenant. However, I don't see the option to configure modern authentication in the SQL server database email configuration.

My understanding is that modern authentication means OAuth or Microsoft Graph API based authentication. What is the alternative to basic authentication in SQL server database email/How to migrate from Basic authentication to modern authentication in SQL server?

Comment: Use a proper mail client maybe? SQL Server DBMail is not designed as a mass mailer, it's for DBA alerts only.

Comment: I am only asking about sql server dbmail for dba alerts.

Comment: @variable any luck with this?  GMail is going OAuth-Only this fall (9/2024), I'm in the same boat, how to send dba-type emails?

Comment: Nothing on this, our IT admin has made me to use anonymous authentication (SMTP), and allowed only the SQL server machine to be able to use this SMTP.